# HSQLDB: raise the counter of a SEQUENCE by N

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sequence, hsqldb

In HSQLDB, I try to raise the counter of a sequence by N. I could not find any example of how to do it when N > 1, so I tried calling `NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence` N times, however that also did not work out.

For example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(OUT my_output INTEGER, OUT out_a_1 INTEGER, OUT out_a_2 INTEGER, OUT out_a_3 INTEGER, IN my_input INTEGER)
        MODIFIES SQL DATA -- NO SQL
        BEGIN ATOMIC

                DECLARE a_1 BIGINT;
                DECLARE a_2 BIGINT;
                DECLARE a_3 BIGINT;

                SET my_output = my_input;

                SET a_1 = NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence;
                SET a_2 = NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence;
                SET a_3 = NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence;

                SET out_a_1 = a_1;
                SET out_a_2 = a_2;
                SET out_a_3 = a_3;
        END;
```

Result: the counter is raised only by 1 so that `out_a_1 == out_a_2 == out_a_3`

Is it possible to raise the counter by N in a single operation?

If not, what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the sequence value into a table. Each row insert will increment the sequence.

```
DECLARE TABLE T (ID INT)
INSERT INTO T VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence), (NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence)
```

The example above can be used to increment the sequence by two.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something like that. Glad you could confirm that this is the intended way to do it.

Comment: BTW, I think I have read that with a sequence there might be a problem of two users/sessions getting the same value, unless I make the successive `NEXT VALUE` calls atomic (e.g. in a procedure). Is there no such problem with this `INSERT`? Also, doesn't sequence create `BIGINT`?

Comment: Sessions will never return the same value returned by another session. Atomicity is enforced regardless of the context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.